# Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format

Tags: mysql-5.5, transaction-log, error-log, warning

In MySQL error log I am getting this warning message:

> [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statement is unsafe because it invokes a trigger or a stored function that inserts into an AUTO_INCREMENT column. Inserted values cannot be logged correctly

Is it causing any problem in the server, and how I can avoid it?